# How to require non-anonymous user in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-authorization

In .Net Core, the controller attribute [AllowAnonymous] lets you set a controller to allow non-logged in users to access the controller.

Is there a way to do the opposite, to require a user to be logged in? Without giving all users a role and then checking every single controller with [Authorize(Roles = "WarmBody")], I can't see how to require a login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add custom policy filter

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                         .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        //other code ...
    }

    //other code ...
}
```

Or set `[Authorize]` Attribute for each controller

Comment: See also: [asp.net core authorization docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data#modify-the-app-to-secure-user-data)

Comment: "Or set [Authorize] Attribute for each controller" you could do this on a custom base controller too, a d have each controller which requires authorisation inherit from that. Depending on whether there are more controllers requiring auth than those which allow anonymous access.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need role based authorization, just use the `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller or actions you want to limit to logged in users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple